# Array key value pair from string

Tags: php

I have a string

```
$str = 'utmcsr=google|utmcmd=organic|utmccn=(not set)|utmctr=(not provided)';
```

Need to convert this string in below format.

```
$utmcsr = google;
$utmcmd= organic;
$utmccn= (not set);
$utmctr= (not provided);
```

and more can come. I have try explode and slip function but not gives result. Please suggest.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Good luck. Make some [proper research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and make some attempts. If you get stuck on somethings specific with your existing attempt, or have a specific question along the way, please come back and ask. Just don't forget to show your attempt and explain exactly where you're stuck though. And remember that SO isn't a free coding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "Double `explode`" you can extract all key-value pairs from the string. First, explode on the pipe symbol, the resuting array contains strings like `utmcsr=google`. Iterate over this array and explode each string on the equal sign:

```
$result = [];
$str = 'utmcsr=google|utmcmd=organic|utmccn=(not set)|utmctr=(not provided)';
$arr = explode('|', $str);
foreach($arr as $str2) {
    $values = explode('=', $str2);
    $result[ $values[0] ] = $values[1];
}
```

Comment: Corrected a typo in the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$str = 'utmcsr=google|utmcmd=organic|utmccn=(not set)|utmctr=(not provided)';

$new_array = explode('|', $str);
$result_array = array();
foreach ($new_array as $value) {
    $new_arr = explode('=', $value);
    $result_array[$new_arr[0]] = $new_arr[1];
}
extract($result_array);
echo $utmcsr;
echo $utmctr;
```

Output: google(not provided)